# Capacitor.convertFileSrc invalid url after rebuild on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using the capacitor FileSystem to save and load a file.

I save the file :

```
const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
   path: fileName,
   data: this.iconAvatarBase64,
   directory: Directory.Data
});
this.iconAvatarUrlLocalRaw = fileName;
this.iconAvatarUrlLocal = savedFile['uri'];
```

I am using the file in src like this :

```
getIconAvatarUrlLocal() {
   return Capacitor.convertFileSrc(this.iconAvatarUrlLocal);
}

<img slot="start" class="avatar menu" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(obj.getIconAvatarUrlLocal())">
```

When I launch the application I create the file, then save the data locally. I can display the image without problem, I can stop/relaunch the apps, the file is working.

But if I rebuild my apps in Xcode, then the file is not working, the **img** block can't display its. The saving data is used, consequently the image is not recreated, the link is known.
On web browser and Android I do not have this bug.

The strange part is that "stat" is working ...

```
await Filesystem.stat({ path: this.iconAvatarUrlLocalRaw, directory: Directory.Data});
```

Consequently the file exist but **img** can't access to the file ...

An exemple :

1. Working : I create the file capacitor://localhost/*capacitor_file*/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3BBB3DA-E64B-414F-B67C-34DB4A3D54DD/Documents/animalIconAvatar_32_659.5026582928432.svg
2. Not working : After I rebuild in Xcode : capacitor://localhost/*capacitor_file*/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3BBB3DA-E64B-414F-B67C-34DB4A3D54DD/Documents/animalIconAvatar_32_659.5026582928432.svg
3. Working : I re-create the file : capacitor://localhost/*capacitor_file*/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F3FC606-48CF-4C51-8EF3-BE7D9B350958/Documents/animalIconAvatar_32_960.997327389742.svg

I have 2 methods to solve my problem but I have no idea how to implement them :

1. Rebuild the image if the image is not working. Stat works, consequently I do not know how to do detect the image is not working.
2. Having the link working after rebuild in Xcode

I someone has an idea, I am stuck with this.

Comment: in iOS, all application is blackbox. First time, you build and create file A in workspace A. Second one, you rebuild B version and make workspace B so you cant access file from workspace A. And third one, you can access because all file and app is working on workspace B. This is the reason why when you rebuild xCode it not working.

Comment: Ok but using stat work the 3 times :/

await Filesystem.stat({ path: this.iconAvatarUrlLocalRaw, directory: Directory.Data});

Answer (score 0):

Solution,

To check if the file exist I use :

```
Capacitor.convertFileSrc(await Filesystem.getUri({ path: fileName, directory: Directory.Data})['uri']) !== undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I think is caused by trying to use the same absolute file path to access the image file after the re-build. My app works a bit differently but I fixed the issue by calling the method Filesystem.getUri() and passing in the file name (rather than an exact path) as the value of the 'path' property and then recalling Capacitor.convertFileSrc() every time the app starts up. That way the app will have the correct path to the file (if my understanding is correct, the absolute path to a file in the Directory changes slightly with every build). So the code would look something like:

`const file = await Filesystem.getUri({ path: [file name] directory: [whatever directory you are using eg Directory.Data] });`

`const newImageSrc = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(file.uri);`